# Return Value in TextField

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to get the IP Address to return in my JavaFX application however I am unsure I am doing it right. I am a little rusty in my java (its been 2 years since I last write for any college applications etc.) Would anyone be able to advise where I am going wrong in terms of trying to get the returned host address into the text field. Area highlighted by **

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    Stage window;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("thenewboston - JavaFX");

        //GridPane with 10px padding around edge
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        grid.setVgap(8);
        grid.setHgap(10);

        //Name Label - constrains use (child, column, row)
        Label nameLabel = new Label("Find my IP Address:");
        nameLabel.setId("bold-label");
        GridPane.setConstraints(nameLabel, 0, 0);

        //Search IP Address 
        Button IPlookupButton =new Button("Search for IP");
        GridPane.setConstraints(IPlookupButton, 1, 0);
        IPlookupButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            try {
                InetAddress thisIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                System.out.println("IP:" + thisIp.getHostAddress());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        **//Name Input
        TextField nameInput = new Textfield(thisIp.getHostAddress());
        GridPane.setConstraints(nameInput, 3, 0);**

        //Password Label
        Label passLabel = new Label("MAC Address Look UP:");
        GridPane.setConstraints(passLabel, 0, 1);

        //Password Input
        TextField passInput = new TextField();
        passInput.setPromptText("password");
        GridPane.setConstraints(passInput, 1, 1);

        //Login
        Button loginButton = new Button("Log In");
        GridPane.setConstraints(loginButton, 1, 2);

        //Sign up
        Button signUpButton = new Button("Sign Up");
        signUpButton.getStyleClass().add("button-blue");
        GridPane.setConstraints(signUpButton, 1, 3);

        //Add everything to grid
        grid.getChildren().addAll(nameLabel, IPlookupButton, nameInput, 
        passLabel, passInput, loginButton, signUpButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 600, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("colour.css");
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the text of the text field in the button's handler:

```
//Search IP Address 
Button IPlookupButton =new Button("Search for IP");
GridPane.setConstraints(IPlookupButton, 1, 0);

//Name Input
TextField nameInput = new TextField();
GridPane.setConstraints(nameInput, 3, 0);

IPlookupButton.setOnAction(event -> {
    try {
        InetAddress thisIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        nameInput.setText("IP:" + thisIp.getHostAddress());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```